# Having Difficulties in Integrating a Simple Code Snippet into a Complex Existing Node.js Code

Tags: node.js

I am trying to add a new URL path (Node.js home page has given an example to do it.) to a piece of complex existing code (shown below).  The existing code already has server configuration code but the code looks very different from the "Building a Node.js Web Server" example that is showing in the Node.js home page.

The new URL path is "/lens/v1/ping" that is sent from the browser window.

If that is the URL path received, I am supposed to send a response Status 200 back to the browser.

I am having difficulties to fit this new URL path and its associated code to the existing code (show below) and I am seeking help.  Thank you very much.

```
/**
* Entry point for the RESTFul Service.
*/

var express = require('express')
var config = require('config');
var _ = require('underscore');
var bodyParser = require("vcommons").bodyParser;
// Export config, so that it can be used anywhere
module.exports.config = config;
var Log = require('vcommons').log;
var logger = Log.getLogger('SUBSCRIBE', config.log);
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");
var cluster = require("cluster");
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Fork workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }


    cluster.on('online', function (worker) {
        logger.info('A worker with #' + worker.id);
    });

    cluster.on('listening', function (worker, address) {
        logger.info('A worker is now connected to ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
    });

    cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
        logger.info('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
    });

} else {
    logger.info("Starting Subscription Application");
    createApp();
}


// Create Express App
function createApp() {
    var app = express();

    app.configure(function () {
        // enable web server logging; pipe those log messages through winston
        var winstonStream = {
            write : function (message, encoding) {
                logger.trace(message);
            }
        }; // Log

        app.use(bodyParser({}));
        app.use(app.router);


        if (config.debug) {
            app.use(express.errorHandler({
                    showStack : true,
                    dumpExceptions : true
                }));
        }
    });


    // Include Router
    var router = require('../lib/router')();

    // Subscribe to changes by certain domain for a person
    app.post('/lens/v1/:assigningAuthority/:identifier/*', router.submitRequest);

    // Listen
    if (!_.isUndefined(config.server) || !_.isUndefined(config.secureServer)) {
        if (!_.isUndefined(config.server)) {
            http.createServer(app).listen(config.server.port, config.server.host, function () {
                logger.info("Subscribe server listening at http://" + config.server.host + ":" 
                + config.server.port);
            });
        }

        if (!_.isUndefined(config.secureServer)) {
            https.createServer(fixOptions(config.secureServer.options), app).listen 
            (config.secureServer.port, config.secureServer.host, function () {
            logger.info("Subscribe server listening at https://" + config.secureServer.host 
              + ":" + config.secureServer.port);
            });
        }
    } else {
        logger.error("Configuration must contain a server or secureServer.");
        process.exit();
    }
}


function fixOptions(configOptions) {
    var options = {};

    if (!_.isUndefined(configOptions.key) && _.isString(configOptions.key)) {
        options.key = fs.readFileSync(configOptions.key);
    }


    if (!_.isUndefined(configOptions.cert) && _.isString(configOptions.cert)) {
        options.cert = fs.readFileSync(configOptions.cert);
    }

    if (!_.isUndefined(configOptions.pfx) && _.isString(configOptions.pfx)) {
        options.pfx = fs.readFileSync(configOptions.pfx);
    }

    return options;
}

// Default exception handler
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    logger.error('Caught exception: ' + err);
    process.exit()
});

// Ctrl-C Shutdown
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    logger.info("Shutting down from  SIGINT (Crtl-C)")
    process.exit()
})

// Default exception handler
process.on('exit', function (err) {
    logger.info('Exiting.. Error:', err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A browser window executes a HTTP GET request. After the `// Include Router` call, that is where you would define your express GET function.

```
...
// Include Router
var router = require('../lib/router')();

//*********
//define your method here, as shown, or in your router file.
app.get('lens/v1/ping', function(req, res){ 
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  res.end();
} );
//*********

// Subscribe to changes by certain domain for a person
app.post('/lens/v1/:assigningAuthority/:identifier/*', router.submitRequest);
...
```